# Photo gallery -javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, gallery

I have five images in a div, they look like this [1] [2] [3] [4] [5].
I want to make a javascript that turns them automaticly into [2] [3] [4] [5] [1] and then [3] [4] [5] [1] [2]  and so on.
For now I managed to make only the first image change. Is it posible to make all of them change using the script I have?
Thank you in advance. (I don't know jquery, I'm a beginner at javascript.)

```js
var i = 1;
var x = ["img/facebook.png", "img/linkedin.png", "img/mail.png", "img/twiter.png", "img/skype.png"];
var y = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"];

function slide(num) {
    
    i = i + num;
  if(i < 0) i = x.length - 1;
  if (i > x.length - 1) i = 0  
     document.getElementById('image01').src = x[i];
  document.getElementById('text01').innerHTML = i;
}

function autorun(){setInterval("slide(1)", 3000);}
```

```css
body{margin: 0; padding: 0; color:#fdbf7d; font-family: courier new;}
.container{margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; width:940px; padding:10px; background-color: yellow;}
#photo_gallery_container{background-color: brown;}
#photo_gallery{}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   
   <title>Gallery</title>
   
   <meta http-equiv="content" content="text/html"; charset=UTF-8>  
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
   
</head>

<body onload="autorun()">
   <div class="container">
      <div id="photo_gallery_container">
      <div id="photo_gallery">
   <center>
      <img id="image01" src="img/facebook.png" width="100px" height="100px">
      <img id="image02" src="img/linkedin.png" width="100px" height="100px">
      <img id="image03" src="img/mail.png" width="100px" height="100px">
      <img id="image04" src="img/twiter.png" width="100px" height="100px">
      <img id="image05" src="img/skype.png" width="100px" height="100px">
   <span id="text01">1</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
   <span id="text02">2</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
   <span id="text03">3</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
   <span id="text04">4</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
   <span id="text05">5</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
   </center> 
   </div>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="myscript.js"></script>
   </div>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You could removeChild and addChild or use jQuery as tagged

Answer (score 0):

You could do it by cloning the image and inserting it after the last image:

```
var thisImage = $('#image01').clone(); //clone image
$('#image01').remove(); //remove original image
var lastImage = $('center img').eq(x.length-1); //get last image
thisImage.insertAfter(lastImage); //insert clone after last image
```